# Mule Credentials for EE Repositories

Tags: maven, mule, mule-studio

For my Mule domain maven project I am getting unauthorised error.
Although I have credentials in the settings.xml I am not sure why is this happening.
I am using the credentials which i use to login to the support site.
Am I using the wrong credentials?

Error, just for reference
Failed to execute goal on project suez-connect-v1: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:suez-connect-v1:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.mulesoft.security:mule-module-security-property-placeholder:jar:1.4.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mulesoft.security:mule-module-security-property-placeholder:jar:1.4.0: Could not transfer artifact com.mulesoft.security:mule-module-security-property-placeholder:pom:1.4.0 from/to MuleRepositoryEE (https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]

Comment: Mauro's answer below is correct. Also, you can test your credentials by trying to access the repository using your web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credential are different, you need to open a support ticket asking for maven access, they will give your credentials and the ticket will not impact your quota.

Answer (score 0):

The project's pom.xml is incorrectly specifying a repository-master repository, which is private and not accessible by usual customer nexus credentials.

Solution is to switch to mulesoft public repositories:

```
<repository>
    <id>mulesoft-public</id>
    <name>MuleSoft Public Repository</name>
    <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

Refer this [link](https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Mule-project-builds-fail-with-not-authorized-error-attempting-to-access-repository-master-mulesoft-org) for more details

Answer (score 0):

For folks whose organizations own the Mulesoft Enterprise license, here's a few links that helped me resolve the 401 error.  I'm not a Maven power user so it was very helpful.

[Mule App Maven Plugin Dependency - Forbidden Issue](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/mule-app-maven-plugin-dependencies-Forbidden-Issue)

[Configuring Maven to Work with Mule](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb#configuring-your-maven-installation-for-mule)
[How to use Enterprise Maven Repository credentials with settings.xml and pom.xml example](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-use-Enterprise-Maven-Repository-credentials-with-settings-xml-and-pom-xml-example)